# wcf self hosting multiple service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, hosting, self-hosting

In my project I have two services Service1 and Service2 (i.e.service contracts).I want these two to be self hosted using console.For this I am using service named "myservice" and implementing both interfaces i.e. IService1 and IService2 like

```
public class myservice : IService1,IService2
...
....


ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(myservice));
serviceHost.Open();
```

Endpoints used :

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="myservice">
    <endpoint address="sa1" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="sa2" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IService2"/>
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8001/" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

I want these two be seperate service i.e. service named Service1 and Service2 (instead of myservice) with tcp binding and self hosting.Any code/help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: like Service1:Iservice1 ... Service2:IService2 ServiceHost serviceHost1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1)); ServiceHost serviceHost2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2)); ServiceHost1.Open();ServiceHost2.Open();... what about config settings???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **must have** two separate services - then you need two separate service implementation classes and also two separate `ServiceHost` instances:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
  ...
}

public class Service2 : IService2
{
  ...
}


ServiceHost serviceHost1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
serviceHost1.Open();

ServiceHost serviceHost2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2));
serviceHost2.Open();
```

Endpoint config:

```
<service name="YourNamespace.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="sa1" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IService1" />
    <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8001/" />
       </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
<service name="YourNamespace.Service2" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="sa2" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IService2" />
    <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8002/" />
       </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
```