# WCF : Passkey with WSDL URL and based on the Key point the Service reference to old and new one?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a requirement to create a wrapper WCF in order to point to the Old service reference and new Service reference based on a Key.
I am working on a legacy systems and I have no idea how to move forward on this.

My requirement is like
https://someURL.svc?appkey=key1/key2

If I pass key1 , the service reference should be pointed to old1.
If I pass key2 , the service reference should be pointed to new1.

https://someURL.svc?appkey=key1/key2 , this will act as a wrapper and inside this we will configure 2 service end points.

I need to know How can I get this key and configure service expose service point based on this.

Could you please throw some light on this how to approach this problem. I haven't been working on WCF for quite a long time?

Comment: Generally use the Authorization header to pass the apiKey instead of passing it in the query string.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481894/how-would-you-implement-api-key-in-wcf-data-service

Comment: You can think of it as two separate services - then you need two separate service implementation classes and two separate instances of ServiceHost.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749997/wcf-self-hosting-multiple-service